# Batch File Not Accepting Drag 'n Drop Input

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-10

So I have a batch file that *should* accept drag 'n drop input from a file, however in Windows Explorer when I drag the input file over the batch file it doesn't even highlight to indicate that the batch file is receiving the file input. I'm guessing it's some sort of Windows setting causing this, but I've got no clue what. I've tried resetting the .bat registry entries to their pristine state, and still nothing. I just recently upgraded to Windows 10, if that matters.

Thank you for any advice you can offer on how to get the batch file to acknowledge that a file is being dropped into it.

Edit: The batch file does execute correctly via the command line. The code is:

```
@echo off
if "%~1" == "" goto end

set pdftk=%~d0%~p0\pdftk\pdftk.exe
set generate=%~d0%~p0\labeling\generate-labeling-pdf.exe
set multistamp=%~d0%~p0\labeling\labeling.pdf
set data=%~d0%~p0\labeling\labeling.txt
%~d1
cd %~p1
set output=%~d1%~p1%~n1-bates%~x1

rem ##### dump pdf data to so generate can determine number of pages #####
"%pdftk%" %1 dump_data > "%data%"

rem ##### generate labeling pdf to overlay #####
"%generate%" "%data%" "%multistamp%"
"%pdftk%" "%multistamp%" output "%multistamp%-compressed" compress
move "%multistamp%-compressed" "%multistamp%" >NUL

rem ##### overlay labeling pdf on input pdf #####
"%pdftk%" %1 multistamp "%multistamp%" output "%output%"

:end
pause
```

Comment: Can you try executing the batch-file with the file as parameter directly from the commandline? For example, `yourfile.bat "C:\directory\paremeterFile.txt"`

Comment: And could you als show the code of the .bat file here so we can make sure it handles arguments correctly?

Comment: Is your cmd running with a different user or in elevated state by chosing "Run as Administrator" ?

Comment: Yes, command is running as administrator, but I don't know that it really matters. My issue is that when I'm attempting to drag the file on the .bat file the .bat file isn't even highlighting (as if I were dragging a file into a new folder, for example) so it doesn't appear that it's even recognizing the attempt.

Comment: `if %1 == "" goto end` should be `if "%~1" == "" goto end`

Comment: Thank you SomethingDark, however after the change the issue persists. When I try to drag the input file onto the batch file it doesn't highlight, so the file never even starts to trigger the batch process.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% what I did, but the issue has resolved itself. The file was showing as a type Notepad++, after fiddling with the registry a bit more and restarting everything is functioning as it should.

Thank you to everyone who attempted to help!

Comment: Old thread, but any clues on what you fiddled with?  I'm having similar trouble.